# An error occurred when configuring keychain syncing

Tags: macos, mobileme, error, keychain, data-synchronization

I'm using MobileMe to sync my keychain between an iMac and a MacBook Air. Since both machines run Lion this error message pops up every other system start (or when waking up from sleep):
"An error occurred when configuring keychain syncing." [image: Screenshot]

I have already reset the keychain on MobileMe and on both machines but the error message keeps coming.
Is there anything else I can do?

Answer (score 1):

No solution yet, [looks like an OSX Lion issue...](http://www.adeepbite.com/error-configuring-keychain-syncing/)